# Playwright fails to open the Spring Web App when both running on GitHub Actions

Tags: java, spring, github-actions, playwright

I want to run e2e tests with Playwright Java against a Spring web application that runs within the GitHub Actions workflow.

Here are the steps that I want to do:

Launch the Spring web application, let it run in the background.
Launch Playwright tests against the Spring boot web app

Here's my workflow:

```yaml
name: Run Spring Petclinic and Tests
on: [push]

jobs:
  build-and-test:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    container:
      image: mcr.microsoft.com/playwright:v1.32.0-focal

    steps:
      - uses: actions/checkout@v3
      - name: Set up JDK
        uses: actions/setup-java@v3
        with:
          distribution: 'zulu'
          java-version: 17
          cache: 'maven'

      - name: Checkout spring-petclinic
        uses: actions/checkout@v3
        with:
          repository: spring-projects/spring-petclinic

      - name: Build and Run Spring Petclinic
        run: |
          ./mvnw spring-boot:run &
          sleep 300
          curl http://localhost:8080 -I

      - name: Checkout current repository
        uses: actions/checkout@v3

      - name: Build & Install
        run: ./mvnw -B install -D skipTests --no-transfer-progress

      - name: Install Playwright
        run: ./mvnw exec:java -e -D exec.mainClass=com.microsoft.playwright.CLI -D exec.args="install --with-deps"

      - name: Run tests
        run: ./mvnw test
```

When I run this workflow, I see in the logs that the `curl` response is successful. I.e., I'm sure the web server has started and is ready to accept new connections.

When I open the `localhost:8080` with Playwright, I get this error:

```
com.microsoft.playwright.PlaywrightException: 
Error {
  message='net::ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED at http://localhost:8080/
=========================== logs ===========================
navigating to "http://localhost:8080/", waiting until "load"
============================================================
  name='Error
  stack='Error: net::ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED at http://localhost:8080/
=========================== logs ===========================
navigating to "http://localhost:8080/", waiting until "load"
============================================================
    at FrameSession._navigate (/tmp/playwright-java-15764527846349711028/package/lib/server/chromium/crPage.js:509:35)
    at async Frame._gotoAction (/tmp/playwright-java-15764527846349711028/package/lib/server/frames.js:537:28)
    at async ProgressController.run (/tmp/playwright-java-15764527846349711028/package/lib/server/progress.js:92:22)
    at async FrameDispatcher.goto (/tmp/playwright-java-15764527846349711028/package/lib/server/dispatchers/frameDispatcher.js:75:103)
    at async DispatcherConnection.dispatch (/tmp/playwright-java-15764527846349711028/package/lib/server/dispatchers/dispatcher.js:312:22)
}
```

The java code for this test is straightforward:

```java
    @Test
    void sampleTest() {
        try (Playwright playwright = Playwright.create()) {
            Browser browser = playwright.chromium().launch();
            Page page = browser.newPage();
            page.navigate("http://localhost:8080");
            assertThat(page.title()).isEqualTo("PetClinic :: a Spring Framework demonstration");
        }
    }
```

Would appreciate any help in understanding and solving the issue with this Playwright error.

Comment: Use playwright tracing on CI to get more detailed info on what exactly is happening during run.

Comment: @VishalAggarwal, I tried running with tracing, but the `*.trace` file is empty. I mean, not entirely empty, but no traces in there...